# phonegap camera API restarts application on android

Tags: java, android, cordova, camera, sencha-touch

Using phonegap/sencha on Android, start the camera or library, get a photo, return to application and phonegap restarts the application making the camera API useless. Has anyone developed a solution or work around for this? I would greatly appreciate any help/

Comment: I ran into the same issue today, did you figure this out?

Comment: sadly no. We are trying reducing the complexity of the application

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a device using Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue:

Try lowering your image resolution (i.e. from 8mb ->3mb).

Make sure there are no javascript errors in the code where you are processing the pic.

Are you trying to store the image in localStorage or write it to a WebSQL database? If so, 
i'd say dont save to localStorage, I think there is a limitation on the size. Try saving it as a BLOB in a WebSQL database.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to upload it by webservice through a sencha touch application to a image script with file pointers in database. I am not sure about lower rez because we have to meet specs. I was looking at setting variables for application state and file path in java, so when the application restarts, it can pick it up again and starts the upload. Seems like a very bad bug.